# Rails, same view, different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, view

map.resources :persons

map.resources :people

```
class Persons_controller < ApplicationController::Base
  #the whole logic for the controller
end

class People_controller < PersonsController
  #nothing special there
end
```

How I can use the views from /app/views/persons/ when I access my app from http://mydomain.com/people/1 ?

I get an error about missing people/show.erb view , I don't want use any symlinks

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html

In your views i'd suggest creating a shared folder to store shared views.

```
/views/shared
/views/shared/_people.html.haml
```

Then you can do something like where you want to use that partial.

```
render :partial => "shared/people"
```

You still need to create the action views in each directory but just render the shared partial instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right thing to do is follow David Lyod's advice. It's much better organization and you always know where your shared files are. However, you can still use the same concept by placing the partial _people.html.erb in the views/persons directory. Then in the people view file that uses it

```
render :partial => "persons/people"
```

Hope this helps.