# Forms from multiple controllers into 1view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 controllers: `models_controller`, `portfolios_controller` and `contacts_controller`

Rather than going to separate pages to fill in these forms, I'd like to display all of the forms in a single view and fill in all of the data at once.

What is the easiest way to achieve this according to the current best practices?

Answer (score 2):

Check these out

- [Two controllers for one shared view in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472817/two-controllers-for-one-shared-view-in-ruby-on-rails)
- [Using multiple controllers in one view in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885477/using-multiple-controllers-in-one-view-in-rails)
- [Rails, same view, different controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616926/rails-same-view-different-controllers)

Comment: I can't find what I'm looking for in those questions though :(
Still being very new at Rails makes it kind of hard to relate to those. Especially with the fact being that I need the forms of 3 different controllers into a single view. 

Are you able to help with this Felix?